# F1 Interview after 2 Tourist denials

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, f1-visas, student-visas

My gf applied for Tourist visa in 2018 and got denied twice (in a span of 1 month) with 214b (insufficient ties) first time and for no significant change in the second attempt. [We realized that this was a mistake to re-apply without significant change]

Since then, She got married to me. She has gotten admits to good universities (5) in her field of study for Fall 21, And has been working in a stable job (Accenture) for over 3 years now. Travelled to Singapore.

I am still in US on my OPT, employed and financially stable.

Q. Does she have enough "significant changes" in her profile for showing strong ties?

Q. Also, does it help her chances if she mentions that we plan to return back to India once my OPT is finished (as that aligns with her Master's end date).

Q. Would it raise suspicion if she chose a University that is in the same city as where I am employed? although it is very good University for the program she's going into.

Q. She has a gap of 10 years after Bachelors, all covered with Work experience though. Does this sound bad for her chances?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Since you're in the US you are not a tie to her home country!

Comment: Why is that? I am on a non-immigrant visa, returning back within 2 years. She lives with my parents. And if my ties were considered strong, doesn't that give her strong ties (that wife would naturally want to come back to where her husband is) ?